# Accessing parent window from a dialog in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, sdi

I am making a doc/view arch SDI application.
I invoke a `COptionsDialog` in `CSquaresView`.

```
void CSquaresView::OnOptions()
{
 COptionsDialog dlg(this);
 if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) 
 ...
}
```

In `COptionsDialog` I want to access `CSquaresView`.

```
BOOL COptionsDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
 CDialog::OnInitDialog();
 CWnd *pParent = GetParent();
 if (pParent) {
  CSquaresView *pView = dynamic_cast<CSquaresView*>(pParent); //pView is always NULL
  if (pView != NULL) 
  {
    CSquaresDoc* pDoc = pView->GetDocument();
 ...
 }
```

But I always get `pView` as `NULL`;
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observed behavior makes sense. A (modal) dialog's [owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows) must be

> an overlapped or pop-up window [...]; a child window cannot be an owner window.

`CView`-derived class instances generally *are* child windows. As such they cannot be the owner of a (modal) dialog. When you pass a child window into the c'tor of a `CDialog`-derived class, the system walks up the window hierarchy until it finds an overlapped or pop-up window, and uses that as the owner of the dialog. Regardless of whether you then call [`GetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getparent), [`GetAncestor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getancestor), or [`CWnd::GetOwner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getowner), it is this true owner (usually your `CFrameWnd`-derived implementation) where window traversal starts.

---

Thus, you cannot generally use standard window traversal to find the window passed into a (modal) dialog's constructor. However, MFC records the `CWnd`(-derived) class instance you pass into your `COptionsDialog` constructor and stores it in a `protected` member variable `m_pParentWnd`, inherited from the [`CDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class) class.

As long as `COptionsDialog` derives `public`/`protected` from `CDialog` or `CDialogEx`, the implementation can access this class member.

The following `OnInitDialog` implementation will do what you're looking for:

```cpp
BOOL COptionsDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    CSquaresView *pView = dynamic_cast<CSquaresView*>(m_pParentWnd);
    if (pView != NULL) 
    {
        CSquaresDoc* pDoc = pView->GetDocument();
        ...
    }
```

There are other options available. For example, you could supply a `COptionsDialog` constructor that takes both a `CWnd*` and a `CSquaresDoc*`, delegating the first onto the base class c'tor and storing the document pointer in a (`private`) class member. This makes for code that's easier to follow in that it explicitly spells out, that the dialog depends on the document.

Answer (score 2):

Add a static method `GetCurrentView()` to your view class:

.cpp file

```
CSquaresView* CSquaresView::GetCurrentView()
{
    CFrameWnd* pFrame = (CFrameWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd);
    return dynamic_cast<CSquaresView*>(pFrame->GetActiveView());
}
```

.h file

```
class CSquaresView : public CView
{
    ...  
    static CSquaresView* GetCurrentView();
    ...
};
```

Now you can just call `GetCurrentView()` from anywhere you want:

```
...
CSquaresView *pView = CSquaresView::GetCurrentView();
...
```

This works for SDI applications. For MDI applications the solution might be somewhat different.

---

Another thing you could do is just create a public member `CSquaresView *m_pView` in `COptionsDialog` and set that to `this` like:

```
void CSquaresView::OnOptions()
{
  COptionsDialog dlg(this);
  dlg.m_pView = this;
  if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) 
    ...
}
```

or modify the `COptionsDialog` constructor so `m_pView` is set directly by the constructor, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetOwner()`. Only `WS_CHILD` windows have parents, other windows have owners.

Comment: I used GetOwner() . The result is same. The problem is i can't cast it to CSquaresView pointer